# org-bullets package slowing down EMACS

Tags: org-mode

I wanted to try somewhat nicer bullets for my `org` headings. To this extent, I downloaded the [org-bullets](https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets) file.
I've followed the instructions to the letter, so I'm not reporting the details here (unless it becomes necessary).

I noticed then that `emacs` has become *much* slower when unfolding subtrees, and even moving the cursor around.

I am using `evil-mode` as well.

Is there a way I can understand, test and maybe find a setting where this effect is gone?

Comment: Start without your init file (`emacs -Q`).  Then `(require 'org)`.  Then `(require 'org-bullets)`.  Is it all fast?  Then turn on `evil`.  Is it still fast?  If so, the problem is somewhere else in your init file.  Recursively bisect it by commenting out halves and restarting emacs until you identify the code causing the slowdown.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `(emacs -Q)`, that's pretty handy.
It is - indeed - `org-bullets`. It seems as it were "looking for the bullets", it just takes more time to render them :(

Comment: Interesting.  It's hard to believe there's not still a problem, though, as I can't imagine anyone would put up with `org-bullets` if it caused a noticeable lag when folding/unfolding subtrees or even moving the cursor.  Hopefully others will have some ideas on where to go next.

Comment: Same here -- I saw those fancy bullets as Harry Schwartz was using them, and in his machine it was perfect. Maybe Windows 10 is playing havoc.